# Change style of contents in array only

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var colorArr = ["blue", "green", "orange", "purple", "red"];

function colorSwitch() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < colorArr.length; i++) {
        document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = colorArr[1];
        document.querySelector("button").innerHTML = colorArr[1];
    }
}
```

The goal is to change the bodys background color, everytime the button is clicked. The colors are in the array.

Comment: document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = colorArr[i];
document.querySelector("button").innerHTML = colorArr[i];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for the same.

HTML

```
 <body>
  <button class="click-me">Click me</button>
 </body>
```

JS

```
var colorArr = ["blue", "green", "orange", "purple", "red"];

var index = 0;
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) { 
 if(index+1 > colorArr.length){
     index = 0
 }
 // If the clicked element doesn't have the right selector, bail
 if (!event.target.matches('.click-me')) return;

 // Don't follow the link
 event.preventDefault();
 var selectedColor = colorArr[index];

 // Log the clicked element in the console
 //console(event.target);

 document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
 document.querySelector("button").innerHTML = selectedColor;
 index++;
}, false);
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuaibkhan1911/aw6k8znr/21/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Simply pick a random color from array as follow:

```
var colorArr = ["blue", "green", "orange", "purple", "red"];

function colorSwitch() {
    var color = colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArr.length)];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```